# Possible tag merge: controls, gui-elements

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

There is [gui-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-construction) which is about, well... gui-construction.

And there was created a [gui-elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-elements), where currently there are only 3 questions tagged.

It seems OPs had in mind [controls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controls) (*46 tagged*).

I don't know which one is better but for me they are about same thing.

Comment: IMO gui-elements is better but in context of new users controls might be more natural.

Comment: [tag: controls] could be a subset of [tag:gui-elements], right? I'd say in a GUI there are usually controls, as well as fields where something is displayed (possibly interactively, i.e. with controls inside what is displayed (clickables and mouseovers)). I guess a big advantage of marking tags as synonyms would be that we have fewer tags for which to write wiki's. I think it very good to write wiki's, so that we can immediately identify Q&A's that have been tagged "incorrectly", before tags get out of hand like [tag:table] and [tag:data]. Do you have ideas about what the wiki's should be?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I think `grid-layout` + `controls` should be considered as secondary tags to narrow the scope of `gui-construction`. There is also `output-formatting` but it seems to have wider meanning.

Comment: `gui-elements` is now a synonym of `gui-construction`.  How does that affect this proposal?  Would you like to see `gui-construction` and `controls` merged?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so, I will do this. I thought that maybe e.g. a question about a specific Slider's issue should be gui-elements instead of gui-construction but I suppose broad gui-contruction + functions will be enough.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but [gui-elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-elements) is better, deserves the wiki and [controls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controls) should be marked as synonym.

Comment: I voted for this, but with the addition that [tag:gui-elements] can work with [tag:dynamic] or similar to denote interactive elements; or [tag:output-formatting] or similar to denote static objects like `Panel`, `PaletteNotebook` and relatives.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [controls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controls) is appropriate tag, deserves the wiki and [gui-elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-elements) should be marked as synonym.

Answer (score 0):

No, those tags are not synonyms.